# Business math - what is my break even point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]I recently started a very small home-based e-commerce business and need some help figuring out the financial math part of it.  I was the absolute worst in math in school.  Let's say I paid \$2,000 for my inventory, my total gross sales to date are \$1,900, and my total expenses to date are \$400 for platform fees, shipping, etc.  The buyers pay sales taxes so that does not factor in.  How do I calculate the break even point after which every dollar I earn after that point will be pure profit?  Is it \$1,900 — \$400?

Comment: $1900 - 400 = 1500$ which represents your gross profit, **before** consideration of the $2000$ in inventory costs.  Thus, at this point, you are $2000 - 1500 = 500$ *in the hole*, and need to earn an additional $500$ to reach *break even*.

Comment: What is your cost of goods sold?

Comment: @Bey I assumed that any goods not sold are *trashed*, which implies that the cost of goods sold is irrelevant.  Your question does become relevant if unsold goods can be *returned* to the original seller (or somewhere else) at a discounted price.

Comment: I just uploaded a sample Excel spreadsheet that mirrors the one I actually use.  Based off of that photo of the sample spreadsheet, what would my break even point be?  Aside from shipping costs,  I have no other expenses at all.  The blank spaces represent products that have not sold yet.  Assume that they will sell in the future with no returns or trashing.

Comment: @Vlad thanks — this is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spreadsheet was super helpful :-)

So you spent $500 on inventory — this is what you need to recoup.

You have a healthy 100% gross margin on each product sold! Gross revenue per item is 200. Taking out shipping you are keeping $180 for very item sold, excluding cost of goods sold.

Therefore you will have paid for your inventory after selling 500/180= 2.7 units.

Rounding up you’ll have started making net profit on your third sale.

However, instead of break even analysis, I’d recommend ensuring your per unit operating profit is positive:

Operating profit (per unit) = Sales - cost of goods sold - operating expenses = 200 -100 - 20 = 80/200 = 40%!

Not bad :-)

Comment: I'm a little confused.  How am I keeping $160 for every item sold?  If I sell an item for $200 and out of that $200 I deduct the shipping expense which is $20, that leaves me with $180.  Each unit cost me $100 to buy wholesale so $180-$100 = $80, no?

Comment: @Vlad your question asked about a break even amount so I separated the cost to initially acquire your inventory ($500) from the proceeds after selling each item. Ignoring COGS, you take in $200 but spend $20 on shipping, so you are left with $180. If we “pay down” our investment in inventory first before we recognize any profit then you are ”above water” after selling ceiling(500/180)=4 items.

Comment: @Vlad this is why I suggested that a break even analysis is not as relevant as a focusing on average unit profitability— your comment and spreadsheet actually reflect this

Comment: @Vlad I also realized I had 40 in for shipping for some reason -/ corrected the post. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for your help.  The reason I want to do break even analysis is because once I break even, I can start offering discounts to move the inventory along faster since every dollar after the break even point will be pure profit.  So regarding break even analysis, it would be correct to say that according to the spreadsheet above, I already broke even along with a $40 net profit?  Would the easiest way be to add up all of my expenditures and subtract them from the gross sales?  Gross sales = $600 - Cost of Goods = $500 - shipping = $60. 
 $600 - $560 = $40?

Comment: @Vlad correct -- you'd have banked enough money to buy another 500 of inventory with 40 left to spare.

Comment: Gotcha!  Thank you!